# What is the probability of the box?

Tags: probability, bayesian

Your box of cereal may be a contest winner! It's rattling, which 100% of winning boxes do. Of course 1% of all boxes rattle and only one box in a million is a winner. What is the probability that your box is a winner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On average, out of every 1,000,000 boxes, $\frac{1000000}{100}=$10,000 boxes rattle and $\frac{1000000}{1000000}=$1 box wins.

Divide the ultimate number by the penultimate number.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Suppose that there are a million boxes. One of them is a winner, and $10~000$ of them rattle. So the probability that a box that rattles is a winner is ... ?

Comment: I was going to post something like this myself. A good way to approach these problems is to just make up a population size—in this case 1,000,000—and then compute the sizes of the sub-populations. This concrete approach is often easier to reason about than the corresponding (and mathematically equivalent) probabilities.

Answer (score 3):

[Bayes Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)!  : $$ P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$  You want $P(A|B)$ where $A$ is the box being a winner and $B$ is the box rattling.  We know winning boxes rattle and thus $P(B|A)=1$. You have $P(A)=\frac{1}{1000000}$ and $P(B)= \frac{1}{100}$.  Thus: $$P(A|B) = \frac{1*\frac{1}{1000000}}{\frac{1}{100}} = \frac{100}{1000000} = .0001$$

Comment: It's a bit simpler to just use the definition of conditional probability: $P(A|B)={P(A\cap B)\over P(B)}$ and to note that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$, here.

Comment: Definitely, but I think it's also useful to do some easy problems with more complicated machinery, just to see how things work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple example for [Bayes' theorem](http://www.example.com/):

Denote as A the event when the box is rattling and as B the event when the box is a winner. We then have:

$$p(A) = 0.01$$

and

$$p(B) = 1 * 10^{-6}.$$

Further, we know that all the boxes that are winners rattle, which writes:

$$p(A|B) = 1,$$
which means the probability of rattling knowing that the box is a winning box.
Now, according to [Bayes' theorem](http://www.example.com/) we have:
$$p(B|A) = \frac{p(A|B)p(B)}{p(A)} = \frac{p(B)}{p(A)},$$
which gives you the probability of winning, knowing that the box rattles:
$$p(B|A) = 0.0001$$

Comment: Corrected after suggestion from Christian...there was a $0$ to much in the result...sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$p(A \cap B) = p(B),$$
since every winning box rattles. Therefore according to the definition of conditional probabilities, we have:

$$p(B|A) = \frac{p(A \cap B)}{p(A)} = \frac{p(B)}{p(A)},$$
and we find the same result as when using Bayes' theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution would be $0.0001$ ($1/10000$), wouldn't it? It's late, but it seems to me that Drew Christianson miscalculated and dedocu mixed $p(A)$ and $p(B)$ - correct me please, if I'm wrong.

Comment: YES you are right

Comment: Well I tried to edit the corresponding post from dedocu, but I 'changed to much' and my edit was rejected, so the wrong solution will stay there. At least I could correct the other entry.

Comment: Thank you for the 'correction' and I appreciate the downvote for no reason @Zhuoran.

Comment: I was asked to review this and did the typesetting. I don't know who gave the down vote...

Comment: Sorry for blaming you - I just saw that the downvote happened basically at the same minute you made the correction and I was just wondering ...